# changing constraints values depending on which iPhone the user use

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

Because all iPhones are using wC hR screen category I can't find a way to change some constraints between, say, iPhone 11 Pro max and iPhone 8 which has a very different screen size.

Is there a way to do so? or I just have to come up with a design fitting all iPhone screen sizes

Comment: UI design is not easy. The purpose of auto-layout is to provide a method to change element sizes "automatically" based on device size. If you are having trouble getting your layout to look right across device sizes, you may need to rethink some aspects of your design. Maybe include an image of your layout to get some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think checking each iPhone model is not really scalable and as well seems redundant.

1) Something you can do in my opinion is **start with a base iPhone Model you want to support**, lets say iPhone SE, make your design fit well in iPhone SE and **then at runtime, scale up to the current device screen size**.

You will get a `scale ratio` such as 1.2, 1.8..etc that you can apply (at runtime) to constraints such as `font sizes` maybe:

```
var scaleRatio: CGFloat = {
    let iPhoneSEWidth: CGFloat = 320
    let currentDeviceWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    return currentDeviceWidth/iPhoneSEWidth
}()
```

And can apply that like:

```
label.font = font.size(12 * scaleRatio)
```

where 12 is the font size that fits well in iPhone SE (your base) and then at runtime it scales to the current ratio between your base screen size and the current iPhone screen size.

2) Another thing you could do in UI Design, is probably instead of defining a specific constraint such as `width` or `height` or other `anchor`'s constants is to **define a view's anchor constraints as proportionally to other views' anchor constraints**; for example you might want width of a view to always be half or approximately visually half of its container width, you can use `multiplier`:

```
childView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
```

It all depends on which strategy better fits what kind of `constraints` you want to scale up, and how you want to scale them up, but I think following those two mindset, can bring you to a good UI scaled in different iPhone Screens.

Comment: I think about the option to check if this is a device with a notch. As these devices have bottom inset > 0 in both orientation. let isNotchDevice = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0.